# How to Load Redis Function in TestContainer Before Unit Test?

Tags: java, redis, testcontainers, lettuce

I have created a test container for unit testing, and I need to load some functions for a custom Redis Lettuce command. Typically, I would load a script using a Redis CLI command like this:

```bash
cat mylib.lua | redis-cli -x FUNCTION LOAD REPLACE
```

However, I am not sure how to load the script using a test container.

Comment: if mylib.lua is in src/test/resources you can withFileCopyToContainer(MountableFile.fromClasspath("mylib.lua"), containerPath) and then use withCommand to load the function

Comment: @EddúMeléndez how do I load function with withcommand

Comment: I think you can use execInContainer("redis-cli -x FUNCTION LOAD REPLACE")